# How to handle upwards of a million concurrent clients on a single Java server?

Tags: java, tcp, nio, scalability

I am building a NIO Java TCP server that is to be able to hold up to one million concurrent clients. It unfortunately has to be TCP connections.

What are some practices to achieve this? I am taking inspiration from the Node.JS processing model (and, I suppose, the classical NIO approach): namely one event loop thread and worker threads for off-loading long-running tasks.

I've read about people achieving over a million concurrent connections. However, how is it possible to have the number of open sockets exceed the number of ports available? What about the limit of the number of open files in the operating system?

Comment: I smell a `closed as too broad` coming, at least unless you narrow your question a lot.

Comment: I am not sure how to narrow the question. It's a broad topic - I'm looking for general practices.

Comment: Broad topics get closed as too broad (hence the name). You can't just waltz in here and say "hey, I'm gonna build a million user server, please tell me how". See [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on what kind of questions are good and what kind get closed. On a re-read of the question I can actually see that you did have proper questions at the end. You'll have to excuse me, I'm somewhat sleep deprived at the moment.

Comment: "waltz in here" - really? I am looking for pointers to get started. I don't know what's wrong with that. If you don't want to constructively help, don't comment, please.

Comment: "looking for pointers" is exactly what the SO structure *isn't* really well suited for. There is also the problem you're not asking a single, constrainted question that can be answered succinctly in a paragraph or two. You could expect more and better responses if you at least separated different aspects into different questions, e.g. how many TCP connections can a machine have (thats easy to google btw.) and when asking about limits like open files at least specify a platform. I'm leaning in favor of closing as "too broad" as is now.

Comment: You can have, ideally, 64K connections with one client IP.

Comment: My actions were based on exactly what @Durandal is talking about. SO is **not** the place to get pointers to get started and these types of questions usually **will** be closed as too broad. People do waltz in here and expect that with 3 paragraphs of "question" (usually 3 lines) they can get a library of answers. It can be annoying of course, but if you plan on visiting SO often you'll have to learn to tolerate a certain amount of annoyance.

Answer (score 2):

One thread to accept on one port. Thread pool. Either schedule a request (especially when high load), or pass it immediately to a worker thread.

Comment: That, and you limit the use of system resources by adjusting the thread pool size. Close the connection when you're done with the client. The point is, you're not going to be able to *literally* handle millions of concurrent connections, you're aiming to server millions of concurrent *clients*, each making a request every couple seconds. If the request processing is fast enough and the requests aren't very frequent, you'll handle many clients in each thread of the threadpool.

Comment: Right, you aimed your shot a bit high. Do load tests, JMeter or so. And then there is the (later) option of load balancing to several servers, also for 7x24 availability.

Answer (score 0):

Either do it manually as written in previous answer by maintaing list of connections and invoking select() for incoming data and handling in thread pools / executors.

Or use asynchronous sockets in nio2 which does all above for you.

The other option is to use high level framework like Mina or Netty which adds reusable handlers and much more.

Answer (score 0):

To answer about the only specific question you have actually asked, the number of accepted sockets has nothing to do with the number of available ports, as they all share the same local port.